# Automating dropdown downloads on Selenium & python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python and selenium. Trying to automate download of files from the dropdown menu on the below link for the first time. The code gets stuck after page loads i.e the drop down does not work and gives me an error. Sorry if my code looks clunky. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

s=Service("C:\\python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/aum-data/classified-average-aum')

#monthname=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='AaumDate']")
monthdd=Select(monthname)
monthdd.select_by_value('01-Jan-22')
time.sleep(3)

typename=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='AumType']")
typedd=Select(typename)
typedd.select_by_visible_text('Scheme category wise')
time.sleep(3)

mfname=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='AumMFName']")
mfdd=Select(mfname)
mfdd.select_by_visible_text('All')
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element("class name","sprite-inter go-btn").click()
```

Comment: driver.find_element("class name","sprite-inter go-btn").click() What is this.

Comment: Also monthdd value is 01-Jan-2022

Comment: class name does not work with spaces, instead use this `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sprite-inter.go-btn')`

Comment: The Select tag also have display none and another list gets opened as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
driver.get('http://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/aum-data/classified-average-aum')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#divAumPeriod > span > a > span.ui-button-text"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='ui-menu-item']/a[.='January - 2022']"))).click()
```

Most of these tags open like so and have another list with them that's not using the select tag.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Well you shoul not hardcode option into an XPath `//*[@class='ui-menu-item']/a[.='January - 2022']`

Comment: It's similar to what a Select tag would be using select by visible text. He can replace it with a custom value and fstring it.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Thanks was able to figure out the issue. now able to execute the full code